# Преобразовать строку в JSON и получить массивы значений

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть строка

```
[{"id":91, "value":1, "check":1}, {"id":92, "value":0, "check":1}]
```

Как её преобразовать в json объект и получить значения?

Comment: Идете [сюда](http://json2csharp.com/)  вставляете вашу строку, получаете нужный класс. А далее... вам уже дали ответ пока я писал этот комментарий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант использовать Json.NET

```
        public class JsonObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
        public int check { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "[{\"id\":91, \"value\":1, \"check\":1}, {\"id\":92, \"value\":0, \"check\":1}]";
        List<JsonObject> json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonObject>>(str);

        foreach (JsonObject val in json)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{val.id} {val.value} {val.check}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```